# CS: GO on Linux, Steam client

Tags: wine, games

can I run Counter Strike Global Offensive with Steam client on my Linux mint? Wine?

Comment: Questions about Linux Mint are off-topic here, sorry. Please try http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is reported to work.

Here is a video of it working on Ubuntu.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1R9BrxNxINQ

There are lots of programs that help with the install of Windows based programs called PlayOnLinux and also Wine Tricks and Crossover.  Although I believe Steam will help manage this when it finally gets all ported over.

Here is the more technical wine details if you are into that sort of thing.
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25413

Hope this helps.